Why Can't I change my border color in input field of material-ui?
I am trying to change the input border color to white even if its focused, hovered or just by default.
I have create a theme using makeStyles for the text and input fields but it does not seem to work. This is what I did:
const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  textField: {
    '& .MuiOutlinedInput-root': {
      borderColor: 'white',
      '&:hover': {
        borderColor: '#ffffff',
      },
      '&.Mui-focused': {
        borderColor: 'white',
      },
    },
    '& .MuiOutlinedInput-input': {
      color: 'white',
    },
    '& .MuiInputAdornment-root': {
      color: 'white',
    },
  },
}));

This is how my textfields or inputfields are created:
 <TextField
          type="number"
          name={name}
          value={value}
          onChange={handleChange}
          InputLabelProps={{
            shrink: true,
            style: { color: 'white' },
          }}
          InputProps={{
            inputProps: {
              step: 1,
              min: 0,
            },
            endAdornment: (
              <InputAdornment position="end">
                {isForm && (
                  <>
                    <IconButton
                      aria-label="increase"
                      size="small"
                      onClick={() => handleChange({ target: { name, value: parseInt(value || '0') + 1 } })}
                      style={{ color: 'white' }}
                    >
                      <ArrowUpwardIcon />
                    </IconButton>
                    <IconButton
                      aria-label="decrease"
                      size="small"
                      onClick={() => handleChange({ target: { name, value: Math.max(parseInt(value || '0') - 1, 0) } })}
                      style={{ color: 'white' }}
                    >
                      <ArrowDownwardIcon />
                    </IconButton>
                  </>
                )}
              </InputAdornment>
            ),
            classes: {
              root: classes.textField,
            },
          }}
          sx={{ '& .MuiOutlinedInput-root': { borderColor: 'white' } }}
        />

How can I solve this

You can solve this issue by using inline styling (or using !important) if you're using external file for css styles.
TextField
    label="Standard"
    variant="standard"
        sx={{
          '& .MuiInput-underline:before': {
            borderBottomColor: 'white',
          },
          '& .MuiInput-underline:hover:not(.Mui-disabled):before': {
            borderBottomColor: 'white',
          },
          '& .MuiInput-underline:after': {
            borderBottomColor: 'white',
          },
          '& .MuiFormLabel-root.Mui-focused': {
            color: 'white',
          },
        }}
      />

First of all, you need to target the default bottom line: & .MuiInput-underline:before, in case on no focus.
Then, target the hovered underline using: & .MuiInput-underline:after. This step is optional in your case.
In the next step, target the focused underline: & .MuiInput-underline:after, all 3 of your cases shall be covered by this.
